# How to reference JSF managed beans which are provided in a JAR file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jar, managed-bean

I have a WAR file with the following structure:

[image]

The JSF managed bean `BusinessObjectTypeListController` is located in `commons-web-1.0.jar` in `/WEB-INF/lib` and referenced in `BusinessObjectTypeListView.xhtml`. When I run my web application and I call that view, I get the following error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: /view/common/businessObjectTypeListView.xhtml @34,94 listener="#{businessObjectTypeListController.selectData}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'businessObjectTypeListController' resolved to null

Why isn't the controller class found? It should be in the classpath, is it?

Comment: How are you running the application? Did you simply choose to "Run on Server" from Eclipse? Or are you deploying to a container manually? And which container is this?

Comment: I deploy it using ant into Glassfish.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to have a JSF 2.0 compliant `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` file in the `commons-web-1.0.jar` file in order to get JSF to scan the JAR file for classes with JSF annotations like `@ManagedBean` and auto-register them.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
</faces-config>
```

JSF does namely not scan every class of every single JAR file in the classpath, that would have been too expensive. Only JARs with the above `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` file will be scanned.

You should also ensure that you do **not** have the `metadata-complete="true"` attribute in the `<faces-config>` declaration of webapp's own `/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` file, otherwise JSF will assume that this faces config is complete and therefore won't auto-scan JAR files for annotations.

If none of those conditions are (or can be) met, then you need to manually register the bean as `<managed-bean>` in webapp's own `/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` instead of relying on annotations.

See also chapter 11.4.2 of [JSF 2.0 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html) (emphasis mine).

> ### 11.4.2 Application Startup Behavior
>
> ...
>
> This algorithm provides considerable flexibility for developers that are assembling the components of a JSF-based web
> application. For example, an application might include one or more custom UIComponent implementations, along with
> associated Renderers, so it can declare them in an application resource named “/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml”
> with no need to programmatically register them with Application instance. In addition, the application might choose
> to include a component library (packaged as a JAR file) that includes a “META-INF/faces-config.xml” resource.
> **The existence of this resource causes components, renderers, and other JSF implementation classes that are stored in this
> library JAR file to be automatically registered, with no action required by the application.**

Comment: Is this still sufficient for more modern JSF versions? I'm trying to help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742677/wildfly-does-not-have-visibility-of-annotated-jsf-classes and read many sort of 'duplicates' in SO (to many to link here, many should be marked as duplicates). Might web-fragment.xml be needed in addition? Just asking before I'm going to try to replicate the issue.

Comment: @Kukeltje yes. The problem in the linked question is most likely caused by incorrect placement of web fragment libraries. They belong in WAR/WEB-INF/lib not in EAR/lib.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem with CDI beans in my case.

I have common.jar project where i placed the CDI beans. (without beans.xml)
and
I have webapp.war that contains common.jar in it`s lib and beans.xml.

when i call a cdi bean from jsf, i get it is not reachable exception:/

project structure is created using maven :
- maven-archetype-quickstart for common.jar
- maven-archetype-webapp for webapp.war

I am using eclipse/juno en deploy to Glassfish 3.1.x.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Resolved:
For EJB and JAR packaging you should place the beans.xml in src/main/resources/META-INF/.
For WAR packaging you should place the beans.xml in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/.
Remember that only .java files should be put in the src/main/java and src/test/java directories. Resources like .xml files should be in src/main/resources.

from topic:
[CDI: beans.xml, where do I put you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056336/cdi-beans-xml-where-do-i-put-you)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the class BusinessObjectTypeListController is founded properly but does not instantiated.

How you create the instance of class on a view? If you use a BeanFactory review the config xml files