# How to refer to a property outside war using JSF 2 EL?

Tags: java, jsf-2, facelets, el, war

**(Environment:JSF 2 with Facelets, JBoss 6, EJB 3, )**

I have a WAR within an EAR project. Is it possible to refer to properties of classes in other JAR files within Ear. I mean, is  `#{managedBean.anotherClass.yetAnother.property}`  valid where managedBean is inside WEB-INF/classes of View.war and the classes `AnotherClass` and `YetAnother` are in Another.jar?

```
BigProject.ear 
       |
       +  Another.jar
       +  View.war
```

If it is valid, then can you give me hint what can raise PropertyNotFoundException? Are there any configuration required ?

A try to save the question from closing:
There is a difference between my scenario the one mentioned in comments by @BalusC. There, he/she is tyring to reference to managed bean, whereas, in my case managed bean is still in the same war, I am looking for a normal POJO property which is in another jar.

**[EDIT]**
Ok, so here is complete exception. The class PojoOne doesn't have property but it does have a method "getPojoCustomer()"

```
2011-10-28 16:50:33,996 SEVERE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) Error Rendering View[/startup.xhtml]: javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /startup.xhtml @24,177 itemLabel="#{pojoOne.getPojoCustomer().getOrganisationId()}": The class 'org.example.PojoOne' does not have the property 'getPojoCustomer'.
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.get(UIComponentBase.java:2228)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getSelectItems(InputRenderer.java:69)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonelistbox.SelectOneListboxRenderer.encodeSelectItems(SelectOneListboxRenderer.java:124)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonelistbox.SelectOneListboxRenderer.encodeInput(SelectOneListboxRenderer.java:107)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonelistbox.SelectOneListboxRenderer.encodeMarkup(SelectOneListboxRenderer.java:69)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonelistbox.SelectOneListboxRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectOneListboxRenderer.java:50)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:849)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:60)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:48)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:389)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181)
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285)
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /startup.xhtml @24,177 itemLabel="#{pojoOne.getPojoCustomer().getOrganisationId()}": The class 'org.example.PojoOne' does not have the property 'getPojoCustomer'.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.get(UIComponentBase.java:2226)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference JSF managed beans in a JAR file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663818/how-to-reference-jsf-managed-beans-in-a-jar-file)

Comment: thanks BalusC, but my managed bean is in the same war unlike the above question. But it refers to a class in another jar. That means, there is no JSF specific code or annotation in AnotherClass or YetAnother classes.

Comment: Oh. Then I got confused with your concrete problem. Please post the exception message and trace. Now it starts to look like that you simply didn't instantiate any nested properties (JSF/EL won't do that for you) and the way how you packaged the classes wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /startup.xhtml @24,177 itemLabel="#{pojoOne.getPojoCustomer().getOrganisationId()}": The class 'org.example.PojoOne' does not have the property 'getPojoCustomer'.

You should access the properties as follows:

```
itemLabel="#{pojoOne.pojoCustomer.organisationId}"
```

Comment: Just for anyone else looking, one should remember naming conventions. If you have property called PCustomer it will be referred as PCustomer and not pCustomer