# JBoss 7.1 Weld finds Managed Bean in a jar in the ear, but the war does not

Tags: jsf, jboss7.x, managed-bean, jboss-weld

jboss-as-7.1.1, dynamic web module 3.0, JSF 2.0 (Mojarra), Eclipse Indigo sr2

I have an EAR, Ynale.ear, which contains a YnaleImpl.jar and a Ynale.war:

```
Ynale.ear
  |-YnaleWeb.war
  |   |-META-INF
  |   |   |-MANIFEST.MF:
  |   |         Manifest-Version: 1.0
  |   |         Class-Path: deployment.Ynale.ear.YnaleImpl
  |   |
  |   |-WEB-INF
  |   |   |-beans.xml
  |   |   |       (empty)
  |   |   |
  |   |   |-faces-config.xml:
  |   |   |       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  |   |   |       <faces-config version="2.0" 
  |   |   |           xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  |   |   |           xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
  |   |   |           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  |   |   |           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
  |   |   |        </faces-config>
  |   |   |
  |   |   |-web.xml:
  |   |          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  |   |          <web-app version="3.0" 
  |   |              xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  |   |              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  |   |              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
  |   |              <display-name>YnaleWeb</display-name>
  |   |              <context-param>
  |   |                  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  |   |                  <param-value>server</param-value>
  |   |              </context-param>
  |   |              <context-param>
  |   |                  <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
  |   |                  <param-value>redmond</param-value>
  |   |              </context-param>
  |   |              <servlet>
  |   |                  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  |   |                  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  |   |                  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  |   |              </servlet>
  |   |              <servlet-mapping>
  |   |                  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  |   |                  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  |   |              </servlet-mapping>
  |   |              <servlet-mapping>
  |   |                  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  |   |                  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  |   |              </servlet-mapping>
  |   |              <session-config>
  |   |                  <session-timeout>300</session-timeout>
  |   |                  <cookie-config>
  |   |                      <name>JSESSIONID</name>
  |   |                  </cookie-config>
  |   |                  <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
  |   |              </session-config>
  |   |         </web-app>
  |   |
  |   |-Login.xhtml
  |            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  |            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  |                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  |                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  |                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  |            <h:head>
  |                <title>YNALE Log in page</title>
  |            </h:head>
  |            <f:view>
  |                <body>   
  |                    <div>#{textValue.value()}</div>
  |                </body>
  |            </f:view>
  |            </html>
  |
  |-lib
      |-META_INF
      |      jboss-deployment-structure.xml:
      |          <jboss-deployment-structure>
      |              <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
      |              <deployment>
      |                  <dependecies>
      |                      <module name="deployment.Ynale.ear.YnaleImpl" export="true"/>
      |                  </dependencies>
      |              </deployment>
      |              <module name="deployment.Ynale.ear.YnaleImpl" >
      |                  <resources>
      |                      <resource-root path="lib/YnaleImpl.jar" />
      |                  </resources>
      |              </module>
      |          </jboss-deployment-structure>
      |
      |-YnaleImpl.jar:
          |-META-INF
          |     beans.xml:
          |         (empty)
          |     MANIFEST.MF:
          |         Manifest-Version: 1.0
          |
          |-org
              |-ynale
                  |-utils
                      |-TextValue.class
                                package org.ynale.utils;

                                import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
                                import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

                                @ManagedBean
                                @RequestScoped
                                public class TextValue {
                                    public TextValue() {}

                                    public String value() {
                                        return "TextValue";
                                    }
                                }
```

The Utility.jar has a beans.xml, and on start up the WELD system finds it and logs:

```
WELD-000106 Bean: Managed Bean [class org.ynale.utils.TextValue] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
```

In the Web.war I have login.xhtml which has:

```
#{textValue.value()}
```

I get no errors in the log (outputting down to FIN/DEBUG) but textValue.value() is never called. I get no output on my page.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Managed Beans defined inside the WAR itself work fine.

EDIT 2:  Sorry, I do have one and forgot to include in the post:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weld, which is a CDI implementation, doesn't scan for JSF 2 specific annotations, it only scans for CDI specific annotations like `@Named`. You have there a JSF 2 specific `@ManagedBean` annotation instead. For that you need to have a JSF 2 compatible `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` in the JAR in order to get a JSF 2 web application to scan for classes with JSF 2 specific annotations in the JAR file which is placed in `/WEB-INF/lib`.

#### See also:

- [How to reference JSF managed beans which are provided in a JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663818/how-to-reference-jsf-managed-beans-which-are-provided-in-a-jar-file/7663898#7663898)
- [Structure for multiple JSF projects with shared code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code/8320738#8320738)

Comment: I know you are the expert! I have already spent 2 days looking at all of your other posts. It just doesnt seem to work.  I am missing something somewhere....

Comment: The JAR has to go in `/WEB-INF/lib` of WAR. JSF doesn't scan JARs elsewhere. CDI, however, does. If you replace `@ManagedBean` by `@Named` (and import `@RequestScoped` from `javax.enterprise.context` instead), then it ought to work. But JARs in the `/lib` of EAR do usually not contain web/frontend specific artifacts, so that would be totally wrong in the first place. JARs in `/lib` of EAR usually contain shared business (EJB/JPA/Entity) code.

Comment: I will try the @Name and see if that works.  The reason the code is in a separate JAR is that I will have YnaleWeb.WAR for access on internet and YnaleWS.WAR (web services) for access on intranet.  I wanted to share all the business logic.  A particular server instance may run one or both of the WARs.  Do you know of a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Business logic belongs in EJBs, not in JSF managed beans. Make it `@Stateless` (or maybe `@Stateful`) instead and inject it by `@EJB` in your normal JSF managed beans which reside in WAR (or one of its JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib`, of course).