# CDI: beans.xml, where do I put you?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, cdi, jboss-weld

I am using Weld as CDI implementation. My integration test, that tries to assemble object graph instantiating Weld container **works well**, when I have empty beans.xml in `src/test/java/META-INF/beans.xml`. Here is that simple test:

```
public class WeldIntegrationTest {
    @Test
    public void testInjector() {
        new Weld().initialize();
        // shouldn't throw exception
    }
}
```

Now when I run `mvn clean install`, I always get: `Missing beans.xml file in META-INF!`

My root folders are "src" and "web" which contains WEB-INF folder, but I also tried to use default maven structure and renamed "web" to "webapp" and moved it to src/main. I tried all the reasonable locations I could thought of:

```
 - src/main/java/META-INF/beans.xml
 - src/test/java/META-INF/beans.xml
 - web/WEB-INF/beans.xml
 - src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml
 - src/main/webapp/META-INF/beans.xml
 - src/main/webapp/META-INF/(empty) and src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml
```

Nothing works so far :/

Comment: In my CDI project the beans.xml is in src\main\webapp\WEB-INF, and in my war file it is in WEB-INF dir also.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

For EJB and JAR packaging you should place the `beans.xml` in `src/main/resources/META-INF/`.

For WAR packaging you should place the `beans.xml` in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/`.

Remember that only `.java` files should be put in the `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` directories. Resources like `.xml` files should be in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: In my case I'm testing cdi-unit (uses Weld) I have to put it in my src

Comment: @dalvarezmartinez1 I bet you could move beans.xml to /src/main/resources in your case; it should end up in the 'classes' folder after building

Comment: @JonOnstott You are right. Actually right now it's in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF but this is just because we're using gradle, and the war plugin expects it in this  location by default. I would say it all depends of the tool which packages the war/jar.

Comment: For me whether `jar or war` I had to put it in the `/src/main/resources/WEB-INF`. Anyways thanks

Answer (score 14):

Just to complement the above answer, here is an official reference on this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html

quote:

> An application that uses CDI must have a file named beans.xml. The file can be completely empty (it has content only in certain limited situations), but it must be present. For a web application, the beans.xml file must be in the WEB-INF directory. For EJB modules or JAR files, the beans.xml file must be in the META-INF directory.

Comment: In Java EE 7 `beans.xml` is no longer mandatory. See [Oracle Java EE Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-basic013.htm)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.javamonamour.org/2017/11/cdi-in-java-se-8.html  here you can see where I have put it with success, that is under src/META-INF . The post contains a full working example of CDI in Java SE.