# Why @Inject not work after import as a jar file to another project?

Tags: cdi, java-ee-7

I have a Maven base Java EE project: `core-project`.
In this project, I use `@Inject` and all things work as expected.
But after importing this project as a dependency to another project, `parent-project`, the injected fields are null.
Why, after importing a jar file to other project, the injection does not work?

Comment: It means that CDI is not activated in your parent project. May be `beans.xml` is missing?

Comment: Looks like the parent project does not have CDI enabled. Cannot really help further as you haven't shared your deployment structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your fields are empty this means that matching beans can not be resolved.
If they are in another package you need a file `beans.xml` (which can be empty).

From [The Java EE 6 Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html):

> Configuring a CDI Application
>
> An application that uses CDI must have a file named beans.xml. The
>   file can be completely empty (it has content only in certain limited
>   situations), but it must be present. For a web application, the
>   beans.xml file must be in the WEB-INF directory. For EJB modules or
>   JAR files, the beans.xml file must be in the META-INF directory.

So make sure that there is a `beans.xml` in your `core-project`and in  `parent-project`. For Maven:

from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13057183/1838233

> For EJB and JAR packaging you should place the beans.xml in
>   src/main/resources/META-INF/. For WAR packaging you should place the
>   beans.xml in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/

Another reason could be that your Bean is annotated with `@Alternative` or `@Specializes`. In that case you need to specifiy the bean as alternative in the beans.xml:

```
<beans ... >
    <alternatives>
        <class>sample.package.YourAlternativeBean</class>
    </alternatives>
</beans>
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjsdf.html for more information on that.

Comment: sometimes [empty is wrongly treated as invalid](https://github.com/jQAssistant/jqassistant/issues/354), so `<beans></beans>` will do