# @Inject Annotation not applicable Error shown?

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, jsf-2.2, inject

I have created new project via `Java Web`->`WebApplication`->`Enabled CDI`

**My First question is:** Why @Inject annotation showing error? even though `bean.xml` added.

[image: Inject Exception]

Comment: One question per question please...

Comment: sure noted on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [injects documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html), it is applicable to constructors, methods and fields. Not classes.

For question 2, please refer to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13056336/2500376)

Answer (score 1):

`@Inject` is not applicable to class. For one this is defined in inject documentation/javadoc.

But most of all, you can open up the `Inject` class in your IDE and see the following line:

```
@Target({ METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR, FIELD })
```

Such line is present on *all Java annotations* and it dictates where you can put such annotation. In this case it is on a method, constructor and field.

If an annotation was to be used on class level as well, the `@Target` would also have the `TYPE` there. Hence it would look like this:

```
@Target({ METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR, FIELD, TYPE })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer