# Create custom jsf 2.2 components and library

Tags: jsf, custom-component, jsf-2.2

I'm a front-end developer/designer, and i had little experience with JSF and Java in general, but i got going thanks to **stackoverflow** and many other great sites.

Now I need to create some custom components to a project, but it is very hard to find expressive documentation on how to do it. The components need to be highly customized, so I can't just use primefaces or some other *faces library due to their excessive bloat to my project.

I did a lot of research, and i got some great results so far in getting a simple component to render, getting the custom tag recognized and creating the name space.

My problem is more on how to use ajax to communicate between the browser and the server. I need to send the data via ajax from my custom component and get the response on the page main scope, so i can trigger specific behaviors.

I need to understand too how to create/compile it to a library, to keep the components and the project separated and maintainable/reusable.

Sorry if I was not clear enough, please ask anything on comments and I will reply. Sorry for not providing code, but i simply don't have any code to provide yet. Any links to tutorials and simpler library repositories are appreciated!

Comment: In order to use ajax in JSF 2.2, the `f:ajax` tag provides all you need. For custom components, here you have [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510729/jsf-best-practice-custom-components-and-javascript/24511858#24511858) you might find useful.

Comment: Hello @XtremeBiker, cool links, the problem with f:ajax is that I'm creating some custom jQuery components, and their value are stored on a variable, like `someComponent.value();`. How can I pass this as the component value?