# making jar the custom components in jsf with maven

Tags: java, maven, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have working on a project that is same as primefaces project.(custom component in jsf) I create component class and renderer class and any thing I need to make it.
my components correctly work in my web application.
now i want to make jar it with maven .i using maven 3.0.5 and intllij IDE 13.
can you help me by saying me the steps of creation jar file from custom component in
jsf 2.1.6?

i see this Error in cmd:

[image]

[image]
thank you

Comment: Here you have some [info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510729/jsf-best-practice-custom-components-and-javascript/24511858#24511858) you might find useful.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Maven project or module, put your web resources (i.e. JSF views, scripts, images etc.) in `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources`, create a `src/main/resources/META-INF/faces-config.xml` and use `jar`, not `war` packaging.

Put all Java sources under `src/main/java` and run `mvn install` as usual.